# BarChart in a table using highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to add bars to each row to visually indicate the quantities in one column using Highchart .
 Any lead will be helpful

[plot graph inside table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19346/pgfplots-plot-graph-inside-table/19356#19356) very similar to the link.

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: Have you actually done anything yet?

Comment: yes i was able to add bar to each row. having trouble in adding axis

Comment: Can you post this code please

Comment: What is it you actually want here? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: In a Table ,I want a single bar chart (with multiple Bar)in one column of table and each Bars row value(respectively) displayed in another column of table.

Comment: Have you tried to render one chart next to the table? Just set all margins/spacings in the chart to 0, so chart will fulfill all the space as the table do.

Comment: could you explain how u finally did it?